# Authenticating user using persistent cookie. Hash & salt necessary?

Tags: authentication, cookies, hash

I'm building a login script and I want users to be able to tick a "remember me" button.
I've read this page on the matter: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/working-with-sessions-and-cookies-in-php-and-mysql/

They recommend creating an auth_key by concatenating a random string with the username and then hashing it with a salt.

```
$cookie_auth= rand_string(10) . $username;
$auth_key = md5($salt . $cookie_auth);
$auth_query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET auth_key = '" . $auth_key . "' WHERE username = '" . $username . "'");
```

I'm just wondering, what actually is the point of doing lines 1 & 2? Could you not just skip out the salt and hash, and just create $auth_key as a long pseudo-random string?

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious at first, but if it was purely a randomized string of some sort and had no identity tied to it before the MD5 hash - then you could have issues where two users end up with the same auth key. That said, MD5 will probably work for you, but technically should be phased out(Numerous collisions have been found with it making it no longer viable) - try looking into a newer one-way hash, such as SHA-2